Why Pandavs did not attained the Moksha?
In Hinduism achieving the Moksha is the highest goal of one's life to get rid of the birth and death cycle. For attaining moksha several paths and practices have been suggested. Pandvas were righteous people. They care for the welfare of others. They fought the war for establishing the Dharma based on the advice by Bhagwan Shrikrishna. They were devotees of Bhagwaan Shrikrishna. For Pandavas Bhagwan Shrikrishna was everything a friend, relative and everything.
However as per Mahabharata, at the end of life they reached to heaven. In Hinduisam Heaven and Hell are temporary. Once you experience all the pleasures and exhausted the balance of Good karma, one has to return to earth for futher progress. This cycle continues until you get the Moksha which is the end of birth and death cycle.
Despite their good qualities and constant contact with Bhagwan Shrikrishna, why did they not attain the moksha?

As per Brahma-Sutra 3.3.32, Moksha concept is different for Jivakotis (ordinary people) and IswarKotis (divin people like Gods who have divine mission to fulfil). Few Perfected Souls (Adhikarika Purusha / Isvarakotis) might not attain Moksha and may be reborn for the fulfilment of some Divine Mission:

यावदधिकारमवस्थितिराधिकारिकाणाम् ॥ ३२ ॥
yāvadadhikāramavasthitirādhikārikāṇām || 32 ||
yāvat-adhikāram—So long as the mission is not fulfilled; avasthitiḥ—(there is corporeal) existence; ādhikārikāṇām—of those who have a mission to fulfil.

Of those who have a mission to fulfil (there is corporeal) existence, so long as the mission is not fulfilled.

Rishi Apantaratama was born again as Vyasa. Sanatkumara was born as Skanda. So also other Rishis like Vasishtha and Narada were born again. Now these Rishis had attained the knowledge of Brahman, and yet they had to be reborn. If that is so, what is the utility of such knowledge of Brahman?—says the opponent. This Sutra refutes it and says that ordinarily a person after attaining Knowledge is not reborn. But the case of those who have a divine mission to fulfil is different. Those perfected sages have one or more births until their mission is fulfilled, after which they are not born again. But then they never come under the sway of ignorance although they may be reborn. Their case is analogous to that of a Jivanmukta, who even after attaining Knowledge continues his corporeal existence as long as the Prarabdha Karma lasts. The divine mission of these people is comparable to the Prarabdha Karma.

Related
What does the term "Adhikarika Purusha" mean?

Nice answer.
